# ng-enter not working when I use controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use ngEnter directive in my angular app

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

When i use it without controller as syntax it works fine.

Working code:

```
<div ng-app="NgEnterApp">
    <div ng-controller="NgEnterController">
        <input ng-enter="onEnterKey()" ng-model="MyText"/>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var $scope;
    var app = angular.module('NgEnterApp', []).controller('NgEnterController', NgEnterController);

    function NgEnterController($scope) {
        $scope.onEnterKey = function () {
            alert('hello ng-enter');
        };
    }
</script>
```

Now in the next step I changed NgEnterController as controller and the ng-enter doesn't work.

```
<div ng-app="NgEnterApp">
    <div ng-controller="NgEnterController as controller">
        <input ng-enter="controller.onEnterKey()" ng-model="MyText"/>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var $scope;
    var app = angular.module('NgEnterApp', []).controller('NgEnterController', NgEnterController);

    NgEnterController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function NgEnterController($scope) {
        var controller = this;
        controller.onEnterKey = function () {
            alert('hello ng-enter');
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try this.onEnterKey instead

Comment: @BalajiM https://jsfiddle.net/gwp5zh56/ still not working

Comment: which version angular you are using?

Comment: @BalajiM version 1.6.1

Comment: yours working correctly both controller.onEnterKey and this.onEnterKey